# Prevent Xbox Game Bar popping up when opening applications

Tags: windows, windows-10

The Xbox Game Bar keeps popping up when opening certain applications:

[image: Game bar popup]

Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way to prevent this from happening?

You just need to uncheck the "Show tips when I start a game" checkbox within the Game bar settings.

> 1. Press the Win+G keys to open the Game bar.
> 2. Click/tap on the Settings (gear) button on the Game bar.
> 3. In the General tab on the left, uncheck **Show tips when I start a game**, and close Game bar settings.

Source: [To Turn On or Off Game Bar Tips in Game Bar Settings](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/76094-turn-off-game-bar-tips-windows-10-a.html)

Comment: Game Bar was renamed to Xbox Game Bar in 1903.  However, the option to disable the tips, are show in all supported versions of Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

I tried all methods to disable xbox on startup of PC, non of them worked.
I object to being controlled by Microsoft. It Is MY computer not theirs!
Finally I went in windows Start, listed all apps then uninstalled xbox.
That worked OK. AS I am not a Gamer , I didn't require it
I now get a clean boot to the Desktop every time.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Before answering an old question having an accepted answer (look for green ✓) as well as other answers ensure your answer adds something new or is otherwise helpful in relation to them. Here is a guide on [answer]. There is also [tour] for the site tour, and [help] for the help center.